# How to form a javascript array by looping through li tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to form an array dynamically with the data present under ul li tag

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" style="background:none; margin-bottom:0px;">
   <li>Popcorn<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
   <li>Bucket<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
   <li>BucketT3<i></i></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried it this way

```
var arr = [];
$('.breadcrumb li').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);

    var value = currentElement.val(); 
      arr.push(value);
});
alert(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/40cka0wp/

The alert i am getting is 0,0,0  how i get the values as

Popcorn
Bucket
BucketT3

Thank you in advance .

Comment: look in the API docs...`val()` is for form controls

Comment: Exactly as what you have - except you need `.text`, not `.val`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.map` - and you want to get the `text()` of each `li`

```
var values = $('.breadcrumb li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```js
var value = currentElement.val();
```

to

```js
var value = currentElement.text();
```